# devise not redirect after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am new in rails world, i would like a little help, i run devise gem and works perfect, i just have a small problem after sign in, i am not get the page a want and always redirect to my index page, can you guys give a little help?

on views: i have my index file for dashboard and for index.

there my code:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :dashboard
  root to: "home#index"
```

dashboard_controller.rb

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index    
  end
end
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index'
    end
  end
end
```

aplication.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Devise</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="user_nav">

<% if user_signed_in? %> 
Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you? 
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %> 
<% else %>
 <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or <%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path %> 
 <% end %>

</div>

<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>



<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

edit:
found the solution:
add in aplication_controller.rb

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     dashboard_index_path
   end
```

thank you, all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application controller add the following method:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)  
     dashboards_path #edited
  end
```

For more details follow the following [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

**EDIT**

Your Application controller must be like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
   # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     dashboard_index_path
   end

end
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried that:


 'def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)  
   'redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index''
  end'

still not redirecting

Comment: still not working :( , that is what i see on my terminal : http://pastebin.com/WyRGBBrK

Comment: It should work, can you show your application controller code

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)  
     dashboards_path #edited
  end

Comment: One thing I am not getting why are you code your method after the end of class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77509/discussion-between-user964836-and-gaurav-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
**end**
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index    
end
```

Why end is there in dashboard controller and home controller before before_filter , please remove that and add that at the end of file.

Secondly use `redirect_to dashbaord_path` instead of `redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index'`

Comment: still not working :( , that is what i see on my terminal : http://pastebin.com/WyRGBBrK

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
redirect_to url_for(:controller => :dashboard, :action => :index)
```

Comment: still not working :( , that is what i see on my terminal : http://pastebin.com/WyRGBBrK